# Why can't a Tanna write a get?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The gemara ([Gittin 84b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=84b&format=text)) writes

> כל התנאין פוסלין בגט
>
> All [Tannaim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaim) invalidate a get

(*my very own translation*)

Why is it that a rabbi of the mishna will invalidate a get (divorce document) by writing it, whereas a rabbi of the Talmud or later *is* able to write a kosher get?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Anachronism is awesome :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's easy: this gemara follows the rather famous opinion of Rabbi Meir ([Gittin 5b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=5b&format=text), [80a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=80&format=text)):

> אמר רב המנונא משמיה דעולא אומר היה ר"מ כל המשנה [...] בגיטין יוציא
>   והולד ממזר
>
> Rav Hamnona said in the name of Ulah: Rabbi Meir used to say "Any
>   mishna [...] in Gittin, she must leave (her second husband), and the
>   children (from that second husband) is a *mamzer*.

(*again, my very own translation*)

Of course, any time that we say that יוציא והולד ממזר the get must be biblically invalid; therefore, the involvement of a Tanna in the writing of one's get will invalidate it, which will not be true for rabbis of any other era.